# C++ cannot dereference end list iterator

Tags: c++, iterator

I'm using transform and plus() to merge 2 lists and it throws an error that cannot dereference end list iterator. Anyone could please help? Thank you

```
    list<int> add(const list<int> & data1, const list<int> & data2) noexcept {
    list<int> output;
    if (data1.size() == data2.size())
    {
        transform(data1.begin(), data1.end(), data2.begin(), output.begin(),plus<int>());
        return output;
    }
    return output; 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

transform doesn't create new elements, it simply writes into the fourth iterator you give it. You therefore either need to resize your list first:

```
list<int> add(const list<int> & data1, const list<int> & data2) noexcept {
    list<int> output(data1.size());
    if (data1.size() == data2.size())
    {
        transform(data1.begin(), data1.end(), data2.begin(), output.begin(),plus<int>());
        return output;
    }
    return output; 
}
```

Or use a back insert iterator which automatically calls "push_back" on your list for each element:

```
list<int> add(const list<int> & data1, const list<int> & data2) noexcept {
    list<int> output;
    if (data1.size() == data2.size())
    {
        transform(data1.begin(), data1.end(), data2.begin(), std::back_inserter(output),plus<int>());
        return output;
    }
    return output; 
}
```

The confusing error is probably due to the fact that for an empty list `begin() == end()` so transform is effectively trying to do:

```
*output.end() = result;
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `output` is empty, you are getting the error. You can use the `back_inserter` for this.

```
std::transform( data1.begin(), data1.end(), data2.begin(), std::back_inserter( output ), std::plus<int>() );
```

If you do not wish to use the `back_inserter`, then you must resize the `list` first. Luckily for you, the list has the ability to set a size with both a `resize` method, and as a constructor argument; however not all containers do.

In the way you currently have it written, what happens is basically this (very simplified):

```
iterator start_one = data1.begin();
iterator start_two = data2.begin();
iterator start_three = output.begin();
*start_three = *start_one + *start_two;
```

Since `output` is empty, `output.begin()` returns an iterator pointing to `end` which causes the error you see.